# Image Metadata: altText , height in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

For many of Custom Types created, we have a Query for them. These queries are being used by Projection Widgets (Within Zones).

Few of the custom types have Media Picker field.The Layout type I used for my Queries is the Shape type as seen below:

=>>> Queries: 
[image]

=>>> Layout: 
[image] . I have followed the steps [from here.](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/ways-to-render-lists-of-things). I specified the name of the shape as : `UpcomingHighlightsImages` as seen below:

[image]

and then  included the view: `UpcomingHighlightsImages.cshtml` in my `Themes/MyFirstTheme/Views` folder.

Everything works fine upto here.

In the View, problem is that there is NO way to read the Image Metadata such as altText, altHeight etc... Neither there seems to be a way to set these metadata firstly in Orchard itself.

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Core.Title.Models
@using Orchard.Fields.Fields
@using Orchard.Taxonomies.Fields
@using Orchard.Core.Common.Fields;
@using Orchard.MediaLibrary.Fields;

@{
    var HighlightItems = ((IEnumerable<ContentItem>)Model.ContentItems).ToList(); 
}

@foreach (var item in HighlightItems) 
    {
        String LinkUrl = ((TextField)item.Parts.SelectMany(x => x.Fields).Single(x => x.Name == "LinkURL")).Value;
        String ImagePath = ((MediaLibraryPickerField)item.Parts.SelectMany(x => x.Fields).Single(x => x.Name == "MainImage")).MediaParts.First().MediaUrl;
        <div>
            <a target="_blank" href="@LinkUrl">
                <img src="@ImagePath"  />
            </a>
        </div>
    }
```

So, as seen in above code and the  tag, I need:

- Set the altText, altHeight property of Image in ORchard CMS
- Read these in my view , the way I read `LinkUrl` and `ImagePath`

Please guide me !

Answer (score 0):

See how you got the first media part in that `ImagePath` expression? Well, then you can take that part and get `Title`, `Caption`, `AlternateText`, etc. from it. You can also `As<ImagePart>()` it and get its `Width` and `Height`.